# Android button not clickable after animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-button

so im having problems with android clipping the button click area on my view. I have a very simple view for the moment and before any animations, the width of the view is being limited to the size of the buttons contained within it, even though i am telling to to be fill_parent in both width and height.

I have the drawing for the animation working correctly with setClipChildren(false), but this is still stopping the buttons from being clicked. I am also correctly moving the actual button's view because when one of the buttons (i have 5 in this animation all moving independently) moves directly above the initial starting position it is able to be clicked and i receive the even correctly.

here is the code im using for the outer-most view (i have 2 to simulate how this view will be added into a larger project later):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.tests.FancyBottomTab
            android:id="@+id/fancyBottomTab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:clipChildren="false">

        </com.tests.FancyBottomTab>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

then here is what the FancyBottomTab is using as its layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"  />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b3"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b4"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b5"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fancyRedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/fancy_red_button"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE: just assume that the animations are in a semicricle pattern of width 100dp and the buttons are evenly spaced and the views correctly moved. Hopefully this clears up a few things and helps find a solution.

UPDATE AGAIN: ok, this time someone should be able to help me figure out what is wrong, ive edited the background so that the on in the RelativeLayout containing the buttons is half-transparent (the grey in the image below), and then the background on the outer RelativeLayout is white. Now the outer RelativeLayout must remain a relative layout for layout purposes later, but here is the XML being used for it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <com.dobango.tests.FancyBottomTab
            android:id="@+id/fancyBottomTab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        </com.dobango.tests.FancyBottomTab>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a screen shot of with the added colors that should make it abundantly clear that something is wrong, but i just cant see it at all.

[image]

Comment: All your buttons are stacked?

Comment: inside a relative layout, use relative positionning in your xml to place your widgets : layout_below, above, toLeftOf, etc.

Comment: yes, they all start out in exactly the same position, but are then animated into different positions where i then manually place the view so that it SHOULD receive the touch events, but im pretty sure that somewhere it is getting clipped just like it normally was until i added the setClipChildren(false)

Comment: I tried using those more specific relative positioning xml attributes, but they dont allow me to center horizontal and stay at the bottom as well as the xml im already using. And my animations didnt look right with those

Comment: Also, i tried making the red main button that starts the animation to become invisible after animating the buttons in, and all of them are able to receive the touch input in their initial positions, but not when they are animated out, for that only the button directly above the main red button works.

Comment: Removing the call to setClipChildren(false) makes the buttons no longer visible except for the button directly above the red button, this button is also the only one able to be clicked...

Comment: How are you able to tell when a button is clicked? Maybe the problem is in your Java.

Comment: I have a toast message popup when the onclick is called for that button...

Comment: I think that my problem is that for some reason, the view refuses to be wider than the red button even though i tell it to fill_parent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i have no idea WHY this was absolutely necessary to get the view to show up correctly, especially since i already said the same exact thing in the XML files, but this line completely solved the issues:

```
   view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

If anyone knows why i had to put this line in my custom Relative Layout class, please comment and explain. Thanks.